# Is there any way to access to the 2nd level of an array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I've created a super array which have 4 levels.

Here is the beast :

```
array(4) {
  ["arrayCoordinateur"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["siret"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(14) "44306184100039"
    }
    ["sigle"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "NdP"
    }
  }
  ["arrayGroupMember"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["siret"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(14) "44306184100039"
      [1]=>
      string(14) "44306184100039"
    }
    ["sigle"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "rerzrez"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "Autre"
    }
  }
  ["arrayPartEnt"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["sigle"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "Blabla"
      [1]=>
      string(11) "CharbonBleu"
      [2]=>
      string(3) "JsP"
    }
    ["siret"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(14) "77408201000034"
      [1]=>
      string(14) "51133834500024"
      [2]=>
      string(14) "40794236600011"
    }
  }
  ["arrayPartenExt"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["sigle"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "BNN"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "13456"
    }
    ["siret"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(14) "00000000000000"
    }
  }
}
```

as you can see, the structure is comped of 4 Array who have all subs array called "siret" and "sigle".

I would like to be able to loop only on those siret and sigle without being annoyed by the first level, to put them into a table.

Here is my table :

```
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($allPartenaires as $partenaire=>$data) {
            for ($i=0; $i < count($data) ; $i++) { 
            echo "<tr>
                    <td>
                        ".$data['sigle'][$i]."
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        ".$data['siret'][$i]."
                    </td>
                  </tr>";
            }
        }
```

$allPartenaires being the super array at the beginning of this post.

This code doesn't work since all the subarray dont have the same size...

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: you might want to look into `RecursiveArrayIterator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
$data = array(
    "arrayCoordinateur"=>array(
        "siret"=>array(
            "44306184100039",
        ),
        "sigle"=>array(
            "NdP",
        ),
    ),

    "arrayGroupMember"=>array(
        "siret"=>array(
            "44306184100039",
            "44306184100039",
        ),
        "sigle"=>array(
            "rerzrez",
            "Autre",
        ),
    ),

    "arrayPartEnt"=>array(
        "siret"=>array(
            "77408201000034",
            "51133834500024",
            "40794236600011",
        ),
        "sigle"=>array(
            "Blabla",
            "CharbonBleu",
            "JsP",
            "Something",
        ),
    ),

);


echo '<table>';
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $length = count($value['siret']) > count($value['sigle']) ? count($value['siret']) : count($value['sigle']);
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {   //Now it works even if siret and single doesn't have same number of elemenets
        $v1 = '-';
        $v2 = '-';
        if (isset($value['siret'][$i])) {
            $v1 = $value['siret'][$i];
        }
        if (isset($value['sigle'][$i])) {
            $v2 = $value['sigle'][$i];
        }
        echo 
        '
            <tr>
                <td>'.$v1.'</td>
                <td>'.$v2.'</td>
            </tr>
        ';
    }
}
echo '</table>';
```

Result:

```
44306184100039  NdP
44306184100039  rerzrez
44306184100039  Autre
77408201000034  Blabla
51133834500024  CharbonBleu
40794236600011  JsP
-               Something
```

Comment: I would to not have to modify the existing array that much :/ , also your solution isn't display the case of the last subarray 'PartenExt' who have 2 sigles but only 1 siret, I would need the 2nd siret cell to be empty

Comment: I updated the answer so it can display all the values even if siret and single don't have the same number of elemenets.

Comment: Also I dont understand the modification that you've made in $data, can you please explain it ? :/

Comment: By mistake i thought that your data had one more level. I corrected now and i really think is exactly what you want.

Comment: It's WORKING, you had made a typo by changing sigle to single ^^' but everything is fine now ! thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh, yes. It is sigle.. I ''ll update my answer for future proofing. I 'm glad that i helped you.

Answer (score 0):

nested foreach loops are what you need

```
foreach ($allPartenaires as $data) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($data as $nestedArray) {
         foreach($nestedArray as $content) {
             echo "<td>{$content}</td>";
          }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Since all subarray('siret' and 'sigle') aren't the same size, it's doesn't really work...or maybe i've misunderstood your answer :/

Comment: Try it. Btw, if I understood your data structure you have:
> super array
> it contains array with 2 elements (siret, sigle)
> siret array have X elements, single array have Y elements

My nested loops uses this structure to dynamically print the content ($content) of every siret and single array

Comment: Your solution, is displaying all the required data but this display is odd...
http://puu.sh/l1RJL/5dce5d3055.png, It doesn't create a new line for every new sigle :/

Comment: What a new line should content?

Comment: Every line must start by a sigle in her first cell, then the second cell should(most of the time) contain the siret then we start a new line with the next sigle etc...

Comment: Ok, sorry for my misunderstanding. I'm glad you already find out a solution